# Problema con tkinter, threading y while infinito

Tags: python, tkinter, hilos

Tal vez es repetitiva mi pregunta pero tengo un problema con tkinter pues se bloquea cuando llamo a una funcion `while` infinito.
Intente usar threading pero igual se bloquea pues deseo crear una función que tenga dos botones, si el botón esta seleccionado llama a la función while, el cual convierte los numeros de la variable value a otro número, esta función mas adelante la utilizare en mi código principal, pues actualemente estoy probando como se comporta la función con la interfaz, pero al ejecutarlo se bloquea. Actualmente estoy imprimiendo el resultado de la variable `x` pero en un futuro quiero graficar el valor de esa variable en un grafico de matplotlib en tiempo real pues estara mostrando los valores de un sensor y guardara esos valores en un archivo de texto.
Aqui esta el código que actualemente se bloquea.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import threading as th
root = tk.Tk()
value = 200
ph = tk.DoubleVar()
f = open('datos_mv.txt', 'a')
f.write(str(value) + "\n")
f.close()

def funcion_ph():
    while -400 <= value <= 400:
        time.sleep(2)
        x = 7 - (value / 57.14)
        y = 5.8
        print(x)
def click_button(h):
    if h == 1:
        boton1.config(state='disabled')
        boton2.config(state='normal')
        t1 = th.Thread(target=funcion_ph())
        t1.start()
    if h == 2:
        boton2.config(state='disabled')  # este boton es solo para probar si el primer boton se habilita
        boton1.config(state='normal')
        print(2)
boton1 = tk.Button(root, text='Acidez',
                   fg='white', bg='dodger blue', activebackground='deep sky blue3',
                   activeforeground='white', width=10, height=1, font='Calibri, 13',
                   command=lambda: click_button(1))
boton1.place(x=20, y=60)
boton2 = tk.Button(root, text='Conductividad',
                   fg='white', bg='dodger blue', activebackground='deep sky blue3',
                   activeforeground='white', width=11, height=1, font='Calibri, 13',
                   command=lambda: click_button(2))
boton2.place(x=160, y=60)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema está aquí:

```
t1 = th.Thread(target=funcion_ph())
                                ^^
                                ^^
```

con ello lo que haces es **ejecutar la función en el hilo principal** y pasarle su **retorno al hilo** mediante el argumento `target`. Lógicamente el ciclo `while`, y en concreto `time.sleep`, bloquea el mainloop de Tkinter.

A `target` le tienes que pasar una referencia al propio callable a ejecutar en el hilo, por tanto debe ser:

```
t1 = th.Thread(target=funcion_ph)
```

Si necesitaras en algún momento pasar argumentos posicionales usa el argumento `args` y pasalos en una tupla o si son de tipo keyword usa `kwargs` pasandole un diccionario.

Comment: A si sere bien br_to, muchas gracias, me fije mas en ver otras cosas de mi codigo y olvide esa parte, te lo agradezco mucho.